# Not able to extract custom error messages from Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase cloud function running locally. Its implemented like this

```
exports.verifyApp = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const {ref} = req.query;
  // some business logic
  
  if( ref === "123") return res.status(200).json({message: "success"});
  return res.status(400).json({ error: "invalid-argument", message: "ref not provided" });

})
```

On frontend I am calling the cloud function like this

```
import {
  getFunctions,
  httpsCallableFromURL,
} from "firebase/functions";

const verifyClaim = httpsCallableFromURL(
  getFunctions(),
  "http://localhost:5001/{placeholder}/us-central1/verifyApp?ref=23"
);

verifyClaim()
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.code, error.message);
  });
```

I am not able to read/parse the custom error message being sent from the function. The `.catch` block only prints generic firebase error code and message i.e `invalid-argument` and `internal`. I can see the response in network tab though but `.catch` never seems to pick up the custom error message I am sending from cloud function.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up [Callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) and [HTTP Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).

You Cloud Function code corresponds to an HTTP one (`functions.https.onRequest(...)`) but the code in your front-end calls a Callable one (`const verifyClaim = httpsCallableFromURL(...)`).

You should adapt one or the other. It's difficult to advise which one to adapt with the few details shared in your answer.

Comment: Hey @Imjaad, did you have time to look a the proposed resolution?